# How to write data in HDFS using R

Tags: r, hdfs

I am using R to import data from Google Analytics API. Now, that I have data imported through R script, how do I save it in hdfs so that it can be imported in hive ?

I get it that I can create an external table in hive and specify a location in hdfs but let's  say I have all my data in a variable `gaDATA`.

How do I now write it in HDFS?

Comment: There are several different ways, it depends on the library that you want to use.. https://www.quora.com/How-can-R-and-Hadoop-be-used-together

Comment: more than likely you will be having data in a dataframe/datatable than in a variable. In case of data.table you have iterate and write data using cat command `for(row in 1:nrow(base)){
cat(base[row,]$MDSE_DEPT_REF_I,",",base[row,]$MDSE_CLAS_REF_I,",",base[row,]$MDSE_SBCL_REF_I,",",       base[row,]$MDSE_ITEM_I,",",base[row,]$MDSE_ITEM_REF_I,",",base[row,]$WK_BASE_IDX_Q,,"\n",sep='')}`  Even better you may define stdout connection using file() in R.

Comment: write.table() also helps you write to stdout() like:

Comment: I would use R system commands to execute HDFS file system commands to put the data into HDFS. So basically you need to read your variable into standard out and then run a HDFS DFS -put command to read from the standard in and move the data to your desired HDFS directory.